# jquery terminal: how to echo to terminal upon AJAX completion?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jquery terminal should echo out to screen upon ajax GET completion. Currently, the `terminal.echo` wont fire inside a success callback

Tried setting CORS but still wont output. this is a client problem.

```
jQuery(function ($, undefined) {
    $('body').terminal({
        register: function (email, user, pw) {
            this.echo("register...")
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "https://faf3fg.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/api/register/" + email +
                    '/' + user + '/' + pw,
                crossDomain: true,
                success: function (result) {
                    this.echo(data);
                    console.log(data);
                },
                async: false
            });
        }
    },{
        greetings: 'say',
        name: 'sterm',
        height: $('body').height(),
        width: $('body').width(),
        prompt: 'sss> ',
        completion: true
    });
});
```

I expected it to return the response of the AJAX request at a later time but this seems to be unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

The `this` keyword doesn't mean what you think it means here:

```
success: function (result) {
    this.echo(data);
    console.log(data);
}
```

This code is invoked long after the code in which is was being set, and `this` no longer refers to your `terminal` instance.  It now refers to the `jqXHR` object (the internals of the AJAX request/response).

You can capture that instance in a variable, which would retain that reference for later.  Something like this:

```
var terminal = this;
terminal.echo("register...");
jQuery.ajax({
    //...
    success: function (result) {
        terminal.echo(data);
         console.log(data);
    }
});
```

---

Side note: You should **remove `async:false` from your code**.  Not only is it a famously bad idea, but it's actively being deprecated from browsers.  I wouldn't be surprised if there are browsers in common use already which don't support it.

Keep your asynchronous code asynchronous.

Comment: Can also extract the callback outside of the ajax call which will avoid setting another variable.